# Deploying keycloak using digitalocean kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, single-sign-on, keycloak, kubectl, keycloak-services

I have deployed my keycloak application to kubernetes. And using external ip from kubernetes service i am able to access the application. But when i click administration console. It shows Https required. How to access the master realm?
[image]